# How to bind parameter, assigning function to class prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

Let's say i have a function

```
function getSum (firstValue) { return firstValue + this.secondValue }
```

and some class

```
class TestClass {}
```

how can i dynamically assign function `getSum` to class prototype with binding firstValue as 1, so after

```
// some code like TestClass.prototype.getSum = getSum.bind(null, 1)
const obj = new TestClass()
obj.secondValue = 2
console.log(obj.getSum()) // 3
```

i could get 3

For object i could do it like this

```
obj.getSum = getSum.bind(obj, 1)
```

But for `TestClass.prototype` i can not set first parameter of bind because context is not existing yet
Can this puzzle be solved **directly**?

Indirectly i can do something like this

```
const firstValue = 1
TestClass.getSum = function () {
  return getSum.bind(this, firstValue)()
}
```

or like this

```
TestClass.firstValue = 1
TestClass.getSum = function () {
  return getSum.bind(this)(TestClass.firstValue)
}
```

but may be it can be done more directly

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you define "directly"?

Comment: VLAZ, i did, please see update

Comment: Did you tried making a `static` method in your project in a `file` named `helper.` or whatever and then using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function that takes one parameter will call `getSum` but supplies the first parameter itself.

```js
TestClass.prototype.getSum = function() { //<–– normal function
  return getSum.call( this,   1 );
//              ^^^^  ^^^^    ^ 
//               ||    ||     |
// forward this –++––––++     +–––––– pass a value for the first parameter
}
```

This gets you the following

```js
function getSum (firstValue) { return firstValue + this.secondValue }

class TestClass {}

TestClass.prototype.getSum = function() {
  return getSum.call(this, 1);
}

const obj = new TestClass()

obj.secondValue = 2
console.log(obj.getSum()) // 3
```

In general this the process where you supply bind a value to a parameter in the function is called [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application). If a function takes three parameters, for example, you can only set two at first and expect the final one at a later point. The whole process can be abstracted away by creating a function to handle this:

```js
function partiallyApply(fn, ...params) {
  return function(...moreParams) {
    return fn.call(this, ...params, ...moreParams);
  }
}

function takes4Parameters (a, b, c, d)  {
  return a + b + c + d;
}

const takes2Parameters = partiallyApply(takes4Parameters, 1, 2); // 1 + 2 + c + d

console.log("1 + 2 + 11 + 12 =", takes2Parameters(11, 12));

const takes1Parameter = partiallyApply(takes2Parameters, 3); // 1 + 2 + 3 + d

console.log("1 + 2 + 3 + 5 =", takes1Parameter(5));

const takesNoParameter = partiallyApply(takes1Parameter, 6); // 1 + 2 + 3 + 6

console.log("1 + 2 + 3 + 6 =", takesNoParameter());
```

Using that higher order function, we can more easily derive the `getSum` method for `TestClass`

```js
function getSum (firstValue) { return firstValue + this.secondValue }
function partiallyApply(fn, ...params) {
  return function (...moreParams) {
    return fn.call(this, ...params, ...moreParams)
  }
}

class TestClass {}

TestClass.prototype.getSum = partiallyApply(getSum, 1);

//example of adding other partially applied methods:
TestClass.prototype.getSum2 = partiallyApply(getSum, 2);
TestClass.prototype.getSum3 = partiallyApply(getSum, 3);
TestClass.prototype.getSum4 = partiallyApply(getSum, 4);

const obj = new TestClass()

obj.secondValue = 2
console.log(obj.getSum());  // 3

console.log(obj.getSum2()); // 4
console.log(obj.getSum3()); // 5
console.log(obj.getSum4()); // 6
```

Comment: This is still not direct solution and seems that no direct exists, but out of all indirect this way i like the most. Thanks!

Comment: If by "direct" you mean built-in way to do it - then no, there isn't. The only way to supply an argument for `getSum` is to use `.call`/`.apply`/`.bind` however, they all require a `this` parameter to be passed in. You cannot pass a `this` without creating a normal function to attach to the prototype either, so `protoyupe.getSum = function() { return getSum.call(this, 1); }` is the closest you can get to a direct solution using built-in facilities.

Answer (score 0):

Hi instead of binding you can directly assign it it's prototype like this:

```js
function getSum(firstValue) { return firstValue + this.secondValue }
class TestClass { }
TestClass.prototype.getSum = getSum;

const asd = new TestClass();
asd.secondValue = ' world';

console.log(asd.getSum('hello'));
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: but i need to bind firstValue

Comment: You are passing the first value you don't need to bind it actually

Comment: I do not want to pass it calling `obj.getSum()` i want for particular class it would already be binded without necessity to pass it

Comment: I actually couldn't understand what you are trying to achieve sorry :(

Comment: i have arbitrary number of different classes and each of them should use this function but with its own firstValue parameter, which i want to set in a moment i assign this function to prototype

Comment: Ohh i see now I believe @Kharel's answer would work on your case?

Comment: class key is used in ECMAScript

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Objects</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function Sum(first, second) {
  this.firstValue = first;
  this.secondValue = second;
 
}
Sum.prototype.getSum = function() { return this.firstValue + this.secondValue }

var mysum = new Sum(50, 10);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
"Sum is" + mysum.getSum(); 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this works for you.

```js
function getSum(firstValue = 1) {
  return firstValue + this.secondValue
}

// or
//function getSum() {
//  const firstValue = arguments.length ? arguments[0] : 1;
//  return firstValue + this.secondValue
//}

class Test {}

Test.prototype.getSum = getSum;
// or
// Test.prototype["getSum"] = getSum;

// or
// const methodName = "getSum";
// Test.prototype[methodName] = getSum;

const test = new Test();
test.secondValue = 100;

console.log(test.getSum()) // -> 101, firstValue is 1
console.log(test.getSum(11)) // -> 111, firstValue is 11
```

Comment: getSum should not be changed as i have arbitrary number of different classes and each of them should use this function but with its own firstValue parameter

Comment: i don't understand what your end-goal is?